# SQL Replace Other Column

Tags: mysql, joomla

I've got a Joomla database where I need to replace the entries in the "created_by" column with a new user ID, but the replacement is based on the entries in the "created_by_alias" column.

╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Created_By            ║ Created_By_alias        ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 62                            ║ Bob Dole                              ║
║ 62                                    ║ Bill Clinton                         ║
║ 62                                       ║ Bob Dole                              ║
║ 62                                       ║ Hillary Clinton                ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
So, I would need the created_by replaced with 1500 when "created_by_alias" is Bob Dole; 1550 when "created_by_alias" is Bill Clinton; 1600 when "created_by_alias" is Hillary Clinton.

I have come up with the following query that isn't working:

UPDATE candidates
SET created_by = 1500
WHERE created_by_alias
(SELECT * FROM candidates
 WHERE created_by_alias LIKE 'Bob Dole')

I get the error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What am I missing? I am in no way a coder or query expert and my usual resource is busy with UW exams at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
UPDATE candidates SET created_by = 1500 WHERE created_by_alias ='Bob Dole'
```

The error you're getting is because your subselect is actually returning two fields `(62, 'Bob Dole')`, and two rows as well.  The error is trying to tell you, that you can test only one value against one field (unless you use an `IN` clause)

Comment: Yup. I was really over complicating things, weren't I... 

I little knowledge goes a long way to making things break....